# mod_rewrite rule for exact expression not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't work to much with mod_rewrite so I could easily be just missing something simple.  I want to match and replace a specific URL. The URL I want to rewrite would look like this:

`http://www.sample.com/hello` to `http://www.sample.com/index.php?page=hello`

My htaccess currently has the following rule in place:

`RewriteRule ^(hello)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]`

However, when I implement the rule and I test it by trying to go to `http://www.sample.com/hello` or `http://www.sample.com/hello/` I always get my 404 error document. ugh I feel like it should be simple and I must be missing something right there. Any help would be fantastic and much appreciated!

Here is my whole file for reference:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?sample\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(gif|png) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ sample.com/hotlink.png[R,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sample\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(hello)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Thanks

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled and the rewrite engine activated?

Comment: yeah - my rewrite rule for non www to www works fine and I have RewriteEngine On

Comment: hm, can you show us the WHOLE .htaccess? maybe your rules are interacting in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfeclty fine for me. Maybe you're missing

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(hello)/?$ page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

or maybe mod_rewrite is not installed or loaded at all.
Look for

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

in your main apache configuration file httpd.conf

Comment: Truthfully, my site is hosted on godaddy so I'm not sure where to even look for the mod_rewrite.so however I have other sites also hosted on godaddy under the same plan and mod_rewrite works on those...

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those times...

I cleared the htaccess file and only used the following couple lines and tested it out:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#
RewriteRule ^(hello)/?$ page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I realized looking at the non custom 404 page that it referenced page.php and not index.php!

```
Not Found

The requested URL /page.php was not found on this server.
```

So turns out with all my edits I mistakenly typed page.php in the rule instead of index.php.  I corrected it and the rule works. One of those times :)

Thanks all!